# Visual Studio run Docker project issue

Tags: docker, visual-studio-2017, docker-compose

I have a strange situation, if I run a Docker project in Visual Studio 2017 I get an error saying: `Cannot start service webapplication1: error while creating mount source path '/host_mnt/c/Users/MyUser/vsdbg/vs2017u5': mkdir /host_mnt/c/Users/MyUser/vsdbg/vs2017u5: permission denied`

But, if I run the same project with the command `docker-compose up -d` it works.
It cannot be a permission issue only for Visual Studio.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just had the same problem - found the solution at https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/897

Basically, the problem is access to C:\Users\user\vsdbg - not to think too much I gave R/W access for Everyone to this one and C:\Users\user\.nuget, just in case, and it worked like a charm :)

Answer (score 1):

For me absolutely nothing worked, including giving full rights to only the vsdbg and .nuget folders.

My setup is as follows:

- I have a primary account called "User" onto which I'm currently
  logged in and do my development work
- I have a user called "DockerDiskSharing" with full admin rights,
  which I intend to use for Docker to run with

What did the trick for me was:

1. I opened a command prompt with admin rights and added the DockerDiskSharing user to the docker-users group by running

> ```
> net localgroups docker-users DockerDiskSharing /add
> ```

2. I went to Docker -> Settings -> Shared Drives, I clicked "Reset credentials" and added the DockerDiskSharing user's credentials. I ticked C drive (my main partition) and the D drive (where my project is located)
3. I opened a command prompt with admin rights and gave full access permissions to the entire Users/User folder by running:

> ```
> icacls "C:\Users\User" /q /c /t /grant docker-users:F
> ```

Still unsure which folders in particular it needs permissions to read/write to though from Users/User...

Answer (score 0):

For other readers getting here which have a forced setup where their primary windows user can't be local admin:

That doesn't work!

After trying out different workarounds, I gave up. Note that I have a local service account which is local admin. If you don't have that, and are not a local admin, I guess you're screwed.

So:

- I reset my Docker shared drive, mounted it again with my primary windows credentials
- I added my primary user to the local administrators group

And now it works :)